# Kafka SQL API take too much time

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have a Kafka and Kafka SQL installed in my cluster.

I have data that comes every second (10 lines/s) to the topic, and I want to fetch all the data that has arrived in the last 5 minutes.

I've created a KSQL Stream :

```
CREATE STREAM test_stream ( name varchar, age int ) WITH (kafka_topic='my_topic', value_format='JSON')
```

When I send a simple query to the Kafka SQL API or in ksql command :

```
SELECT * FROM test_stream LIMIT 1;
```

It takes 7 seconds to return the result.

I have only some small set of data and I don't know if there is some configuration to do to have the data fetched quickly ?

Comment: _I want to fetch all the data that has arrived in the last 5 minutes_ -> Is this just for an ad-hoc query? Or you're building a program around it? Because if it's the latter maybe there's a different approach to take.

Comment: @RobinMoffatt, later it will be a Web Service